# State of art in performance of Raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc, kodi, performance

I'm using [Raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com/) and it's awesome. But i feel a (in my opinion) huge delay to load videos. So I started to find bottlenecks. So here are my changes:

1. Using a very good quality SD card, which has a high read/write speed ratio;
2. Wired connection only, no wifi involved;
3. NFS for shared folder, no SAMBA, FTP or any other sharing protocol;
4. I also have [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) and videos set to 720p, cause it should be faster than load 1080p;

So my question is: does anyone have more tricks to improve the overall performance? And more specifically, the video loading delay?

Comment: Have you done tests to see if the encoding of the video changes how long it takes (in particular relative to which codecs would be necessary for it to use), and have you disabled any "resume from last played scene" or similar?

Comment: No, I haven't. I use the default codecs and mainly MP4 videos. Do you think a different (other than default) codec will be faster?

Comment: If your particular concern is the starting delay, I wouldn't be surprised to find that they have different delays based on how much stuff they need to load.

Comment: I agree, but the default codec shouldn't be the best already? But I'm curious now, I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: for loading time? perhaps not - it would be a balance between that, quality, performance (CPU usage), etc. - and likely the most compatible one as well.

Comment: When running `top`/`htop`, do you find a software that uses 100% CPU?

Comment: The use basically never reaches 100%, but of course, the most consuming process is the player itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some cool information that I found since then.

- @user2813274 suggested to change the codec. So I bought the [license](http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/) to allow hardware decoding. It helps endeed. Thanks!
- Transfer the files from my personal computer to external hard drive and plug directly to the RPi. Using local storage instead of network shared folder definitely made the load delay shorter. I knew that before of course, just didn't want to do it.
- Compile a custom kernel. The default kernel image contains tons of drivers, so a smaller and sharper set of modules makes my whole system respond faster. This is still a ongoing task. When done, I will attach my `.config` file here.

I will continue to add more information as soon as I find out.

Comment: This would make for a great wiki or tutorial when you are done.